# SetLooping(boolean) function won't work in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I created a sample audio player application in android. In my application I used **Play, Pause and Stop functions**. Now I wish to **add Loop functionality** in my application. i.e., when I click the Loop button, recently played audio will play continuously, when I click Stop button the audio file will be stop. I  go through the android developer site, I got a function `setLooping(boolean)`. I set this my media player nothing will happen, how can I use this, in my code I used like this,

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer= new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setLooping(false);
```

Comment: is this problem fixed?? I saw a lot of people with this problem... http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18756

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting the setLooping to false ,if you want to be repeted you must set it to true .You want it to be playing again and again right?
Use:

```
mPlayer.setLooping(true)
```

Comment: Ya, i changed as true, the audio won't play.

Comment: Thanks edy,, it works, but problem in seekbar moving. i tried to rectify it, Thanks for your post